# What does bash do with line 11 here?

Tags: command-line, bash, android

The nature of the question here is broad enough truly to include Ubuntu. I was just picking around forums analyzing this and that and line 11 puzzled me. What I would like to know is, what exactly is it doing? Am I wrong to believe it's related to the touch and mkdir commands? Or is that file assumed already created?

```
1 #! /bin/sh
2    
3 export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/storage
4 PYTHONPATH=/mnt/storage/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python 
5 PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:
/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload 
6 export PYTHONPATH 
7 export TEMP=/mnt/storage/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python/tmp 
8 export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$TEMP 
9 export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python 
10 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib 
11 /data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python "$@"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is basically setting few environment variables (the `export` statements) before calling the "python for android" from this location:

```
/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python
```

with the arguments `$@` passed to your shell script.

See this [page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST) for the meaning of `$@`.

Comment: If you were next door, I'd bake you cookies. Thank you

Comment: You can even upvote (^) it if not already done, see http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: 00 I find myself daunted by the tech in its definition.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I feel like what it's telling me is, What I inserted before the $@ is a location of a file sent off on it's marry way?

Comment: I feel like also, I need a manual

Comment: well if you call your script with `my_script.sh arg1 arg2` then it will result in `/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python arg1 arg2`

Comment: right, I read it again after that one. I came to a conclusion

Comment: This thing is getting rooted ASAP

Comment: That goes beyond the scope of your original question; could you please start a new one (may be on more generic Q/A site)?

Comment: It was a less a question than it was a statement. I can't access /data/data as I receive a piss off, you're not root messege from terminal when I try to drill to the final thread in line 11(exclude args)